# Path helper inserts plus sign instead of space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to have a link_to with

```
<%= link_to "My Link", search_path(par: "My Link") %>
```

but this gets rendered as

```
<a href="/search?par=My+Link">My Link</a>
```

instead of

```
<a href="/search?par=My Link">My Link</a>
```

Is there a way to force it to behave properly, and not manually insert `%20` instead of space?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
require 'cgi'
CGI.unescape "/search?par=My+Link"
```

Example:

```
1.9.3p448 :006 > CGI.unescape "/search?par=My+Link"
 => "/search?par=My Link" 

1.9.3p448 :007 > CGI.unescape "/search?par=My%20Link"
 => "/search?par=My Link"
```

hope this helps!